# Elasticsearch 2.3 has_child with must_not.exists query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to construct a query in which children of a parent are filtered based on a country code in an array. If the child has no countries field I still want to return the result.

I have two working queries:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "has_child": {
          "inner_hits": {},
          "type": "service",
          "score_mode": "sum",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "countries": "AF"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

duly returns an array of results where 'AF' is in the countries array and:

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "bool": {
            "should": {
                "has_child": {
                    "inner_hits": {},
                    "type": "service",
                    "score_mode": "sum",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must_not": {
                                "exists": {
                                    "field": "countries"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

returns the results I want where the child has no countries field.

What I can't figure out is how to combine those two queries to get one combined set of results. That is to say I want to 'OR' the two sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't actually tested this, it's a blind suggestion:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "has_child": {
          "inner_hits": {},
          "type": "service",
          "score_mode": "sum",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "exists": {
                                "field": "countries"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "term": {
                                "countries": "AF"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "missing": {
                          "field": "countries"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "whatever": "blabla"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That certainly seems to work but I don't understand why :(. How does the query get turned into an OR? Where is that documented? Now I would like to add another term filter that is ANDed with the whole query. It's not clear to me how I would do that.

Comment: The `bool` `should` is similar to an `OR`. If the new `term` is ANDed then, to the same `bool` you add a `must` and add that `term` in the `must`. The new `term` is still related to the `has_child` query?

Comment: Yes, the new term is related to the has_child. I want it to apply to both cases (no countries and country matches). I have tried adding a must.term to the top-level bool but it returns all children that match the 'must' regardless of country/countries.

Comment: I see that adding the `must.term` to the new `bool` seems to work, but I still don't understand why :(. Any suggestions about where to learn this stuff please?

Comment: `must` `term` needs to be added to the inner `bool`. I added an example.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118996/discussion-between-kpg-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: Updated the query.